# Keep throwing an error and I do not know why

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to search the datatable for non-unique values and I keep getting this error

> Filter expression 'PROV_NEW' does not evaluate to a Boolean term.

when I run it.

This is my code:

```
public class GetData
{
    datalogiclayer.TableSetup dal;
    DataSet ds;

    public delegate void InvalidTableDataDelegate(string ErrorMessage);
    public event InvalidTableDataDelegate InvalidTableData;

    public delegate void SetupDataLoadedDelegate(System.Data.DataSet dv, string TableName);
    public event SetupDataLoadedDelegate SetupDataLoaded;

    public GetData()
    {
        dal = new datalogiclayer.TableSetup();
    }

    public void Update(DataSets.Setup ds)
    {
        try
        {
            string errMsg = string.Empty;

            if (ValidateTable(ds.SETUP_MWPROV, out errMsg))
            {
                dal.UpdateDatabase(ds);
            }
            else
            {
                if (InvalidTableData != null)
                    InvalidTableData(errMsg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private bool ValidateTable(DataSets.Setup.SETUP_MWPROVDataTable dt, out string TableIssues)
    {
        try
        {
            //NewCode not used for other row
            DataRow[] result = dt.Select("PROV_NEW = ''");
            DataRow[] dupresults = dt.Select("PROV_NEW");
            TableIssues = string.Empty;
            DataTable dtTemp = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "NEW_PROV");

            if (dupresults.Length == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                IEnumerable<DataRow> uniqueCodes = dupresults.AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default);

                Console.WriteLine("Unique Provider Codes:");

                foreach (DataRow NEW_PROV in uniqueCodes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(NEW_PROV.Field<Int32>("PROV_NEW"));
                }

                return false;
            }          
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see I have it searching for unique rows in the datatable, when the exception is being thrown is when I actually go to save the data. And it gives the error that is up above.

Comment: If you want non-distinct, you need to select distinct, then for each distinct select against the result and see if 2 or more show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        DataRow[] dupresults = dt.Select("PROV_NEW");
```

The argument for `dt.Select` is a filter. `"PROV_NEW"` is not a valid filter as the expression doesn't result to a boolean value. I believe you're confusing this with SQL, where you can ask it to select a single column. But you don't need to do that because later you need to select distinct off of the PROV_NEW column. If you want to make sure the whole row is distinct, then this is all you need to do.

If you only want compare the PROV_NEW column, you could write a custom equality comparer that looks at only your PROV_NEW column. You can reference your custom comparer when you call `distinct` with >**[this version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)** <.

Alternatively [Grant Winney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/301857/grant-winney) suggested you could use Linq to select only the single column before using distinct. Refer to comments in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10818110/491837).

Comment: But wouldn't that just search for entries that are blank, I am trying to find entries that are duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following line in your code:

```
DataRow[] dupresults = dt.Select("PROV_NEW");
```

Did you mean to put another value to after PROV_NEW? You did it correctly in the line above, so I'm assuming it's just a mistake. Sometimes a second pair of eyes help. :)

Comment: Alright, but what about this row would need to be changed. I am still learning C#, so haven't gotten a great feel for everything yet.

Comment: @Kobrien what do you want to be the result of the dupresults value?

Comment: @Kobrien He isn't using the other one??? Heck, he isn't using any other variable that he declared

Comment: Yeah I see that now, I am trying to find the nondistinct values in that row, would I do dt.Selet("PROV_NEW".Distinct<string>);

and Xaade there is another part of it that is using the other declared variables, I took that part out as it was unneeded for this post.

Comment: @Kobrien next time add a comment saying so... like // code removed

Comment: @GrantWinney Move that Linq to your answer.

Comment: @GrantWinney typo? Nope, he says non-unique at the top of the question too? Ok, how would you search for non-unique. That would be select all, and return only those with dups. You'd have to search distinct, and for each distinct, select with that value, and return the list only if 2 or more return. Ouch!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this line is wrong:

```
DataRow[] dupresults = dt.Select("PROV_NEW");
```

DataTable needs filter expression as parameter, and "PROV_NEW" is not a filter expression. See [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Check the result of the expression "PROV_NEW". Somewhere, some method is looking for a resulting boolean type and your expression is resulting to something else. my 2 cents:)

Comment: `"PROV_NEW"` is a string, not a type.

Comment: A String is a reference type even though it has most of the characteristics of a value type

Comment: not arguing that your select method requires specific vars or the fact that this is a string..just simply that a string is a reference type.